# jupyter notebook does not recognize tensorflow

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, tensorflow, jupyter

I am trying to run tensorflow on jupyter notebook. I installed jupyter outside of the tensorflow environment by doing

```
sudo -H pip install jupyter
```

and then I activated tensorflow environment via

```
source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate
```

Then, when I was inside the environment, I did

```
pip install jupyter notebook
```

After that, I run jupyter notebook, but when I tried to import tensorflow, I got the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

I checked if jupyter recognized the environment by running

```
which jupyter
```

and got

```
/usr/local/bin/jupyter
```

which means that it didn't recognize the environment. How can I force jupyter recognize the environment? (as I mentioned, I did install jupyter inside the environment as well)

Edit: I just want to clarify that tensorflow is indeed installed correctly on my machine (for example, I can use it in pycharm, as well as when I just open python from the shell).

Edit2: as a response to  @hek2mgl comment, here is what I get:

```
username@blabla:~$ source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate 
(tensorflow) username@blabla:~$ pip install jupyter
(tensorflow) username@blabla:~$ which jupyter
/usr/local/bin/jupyter
(tensorflow) username@blabla:~$ hash -d
hits    command
   1    /usr/bin/which
   1    /home/local/bla/username/tensorflow/bin/pip
(tensorflow) username@blabla:~$ which jupyter
/usr/local/bin/jupyter
```

Comment: you need to install both tensorflow and jupyter in the same virtualenv

Comment: Thanks. I run "pip install jupyter notebook" when I was inside the environment but it didn't work. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: run `hash -d`. Then run `which jupyter` again

Comment: @hek2mgl, Thanks. I added this line, and edited the question to show what I get.

Comment: After the activate command run `pip install jupyter` then again `hash -d`

Comment: @hek2mgl, I activated the environment using "source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate" and then followed the steps you mentioned (they appear in Edit2). Is there some problem with the way I activate the environment? Because jupyter still does not recognize tensorflow.

Comment: Look at my answer. Those steps have just been tested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow these steps, in order, to create a new virtualenv with both tensorflow and jupyter installed:

```
#!/bin/bash
virtualenv -ppython3 my_env
source my_env/bin/activate
pip install tensorflow jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

Create a new Python3 notebook in the web GUI and run:

```
import tensorflow
```

That works.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked. Just to make sure, if I want to have tensorflow with gpu (as I have in the tensorflow environment I mentioned in the question), should I run pip install tensorflow-gpu jupyter instead of pip install tensorflow jupyter?

Comment: Yes sure. Just make sure that everything is installed in the same virtualenv

Answer (score -1):

Try to install anaconda from https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python you will get pre-configured most used component and best for learning purpose. after Installation run cmd> jupypter notebook and press enter. after some process it will open your browser and you will see your notebook.

Comment: Hi @SarmadMahar, tensorflow does not come as part of anaconda, so I had to install it separately. I can open jupyter notebook and import the usual stuff like numpy and so on, but it does not recognize my tensorflow installation.

Comment: Then use pip install tensorflow jupyter